# USB ethernet not being redetected after unplugging

Tags: usb, ethernet, adapter

I have a USB Ethernet adapter for an Ubuntu 14.10 laptop.

When I turn on my computer while it's plugged in it gets detected fine and I'm able to access the internet. The thing just works.

However when I unplug it and plug it in again `eth1` disappears, never to be found again.

Until I reboot that is. Once I reboot, the usb ethernet adapter is detected and works fine.

**How can I get Ubuntu to automatically redetect my adapter when I plug it in after I disconnect it to be able to browse the internet again?**

### Settings:

Here it is in my **/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules**

```
# USB device 0x:0x (ax88179_178a)$
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="d8:eb:97:b3:05:c9", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

Also under **$ lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp.
```

Having to close my all programs and reboot to use the internet again really kills my workflow :(

Comment: me too face a similar problem with my Ubuntu 14.04. It gets  disconnected without any reason, then i need to restart my system to get the connection.